# Determinant of a matrix when its diagonal elements have a certain property

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
l_1&-1 &-1 &-1&-1 \\
-1&l_2 &-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 &l_3 & -1 &-1\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & l_4 & -1\\
-1 & -1 &-1 & -1 &l_5
\end{pmatrix}$

Is there any delicate way to show that det$(A)<0$ when one of the $l_i$ equals to $0$ whereas others are positive?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your matrix is a diagonal plus rank one. There are ways to estimate the entire spectrum which may lead to an answer. You can Google diagonal plus rank one. PS are you interested in this specific $5\times5$ case or for general dimension? In the former it might be simpler to compute the determinant explicitly.

Comment: @lcv Thanks! I am actually interested in the general case, but I think the 5 $\times $ 5 case is tedious enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a very easy way to prove that with only the elementary transformation.

First every column $i$ minus column $1$ $(i=2,3,4,5)$, and we got
$\begin{pmatrix}
l1 & -1-l1 & -1-l1 & -1-l1 & -1-l1 \\
-1 & 1+l2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1+l3& 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1+l4 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1+l5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then column $1$ plus $\frac{1}{l_i-1}$ column $i$ $(i=2,3,4,5)$.

$\begin{pmatrix}
*& -1-l1 & -1-l1 & -1-l1 & -1-l1 \\
0 & 1+l2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1+l3& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1+l4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1+l5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Calculate the"$*$", we know that $*<0$.  $\Box$

Comment: I thought the comment above is also very helpful.

Comment: A typo: plus $\frac{1}{l_i+1}$ column $i$ instead of  plus $\frac{1}{l_i-1}$ column $i$, but in general this is a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks for your correction.Also you may want to try the order-reducing formula because $A=D+\alpha\beta^{\prime}$ and D is invertible.