# Determinant of "quasi-circulant" matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Several weeks ago I asked a question regarding the determinant of a $5 \times 5$ matrix: [Determinant of a matrix when its diagonal elements have a certain property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153034/determinant-of-a-matrix-when-its-diagonal-elements-have-a-certain-property)

Here I would like to consider a more general problem:the non-diagonal element will still share a circulant fashion, whereas some of them can be $0$ instead of all being $-1$. To be more specific, it follows a pattern that in each row, the first $i^{th}$ elements that follow the diagonal element are $-1$ while the rest are $0$.

For instance, in a $5\times5$ case, things can be

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
l_1&-1 &-1 &-1&0 \\
0&l_2 &-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 0 &l_3 & -1 &-1\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & l_4 & -1\\
-1 & -1 &-1 & 0 &l_5
\end{pmatrix}$

or

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
l_1&-1 &-1 &0 &0 \\
0&l_2 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &l_3 & -1 &-1\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & l_4 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &l_5
\end{pmatrix}$

Again, I would like to know if there is any delicate way to show that **det$(A)<0$ when one of the $l_i$ equals to $0$ whereas others are positive.**

Some of my thoughts:
Consider $l_1=l_2=...=l_n=l$($n$ is the dimension of the matrix). In this case, $A$ is a circulant matrix, and det($A$) can be demonstrated as a polynomial of $l$. It suffices to show that $l^n$ is the only term with positive coefficient, yet for me this is something too tedious to show.(with all those roots of unity to deal with)

I have also tried the matrix determinant lemma, which is helpful when all the non-diagonal elements are $-1$ but not that helpful when some of the non-diagonal elements are $0$.

Any hints or ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Sorry for not making this clear in the first place, but this is just a conjecture (though I believe this is correct). A counterexample will also be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: You know that the fact regarding $\det(A)<0$ is true, or are you asking for its confirmation? I'm just making sure that it's known to be correct, before trying to look at it more. Another thing : is this true precisely for $5 \times 5$ matrices? I'm wondering if the same held for $3\times 3$ matrices as well, where I can maybe try to brute force something.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you for your comment! The fact is I don't know whether det$(A)<0$ is true, though I have tried dozens of matrices but can't find a counterexample. It would be great if you can raise one! Regarding your second point, I hope to prove this for the general $n \times n$ case but not just the $5 \times 5$ case. The $3 \times 3$ case you mentioned is easy to verify, for there are only 2 subcases.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try my best to give attention to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counter example:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & -1.0 & 0 & -1.0 & -1.0\\-1.0 & 0.391134657778849 & 0 & -1.0 & 0 & -1.0\\-1.0 & -1.0 & 0.391134657778849 & 0 & -1.0 & 0\\0 & -1.0 & -1.0 & 0.391134657778849 & 0 & -1.0\\-1.0 & 0 & -1.0 & -1.0 & 0.391134657778849 & 0\\0 & -1.0 & 0 & -1.0 & -1.0 & 0.391134657778849\end{matrix}\right]
$$

It has a determinant of 10.609672399765413.

Here is another one (determinant of 0.99):
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & -1.0 & 0\\0 & 0.10 & 0 & -1.0\\-1.0 & 0 & 0.10 & 0\\0 & -1.0 & 0 & 0.10\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Comment: Thank you for your examples! Nevertheless, as I said in the description of the problem, "the first $i^{th}$ elements that follow the diagonal element are $−1$", which means the first diagonal above the main diagonal shall consist of $-1$ only. Anyway, nice try in the Trick Room :)